# Is Directory.Delete() / .Create() synchronous?

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System.IO;
Directory.Delete("someFolder",true);
Directory.Create("someFolder");
```

Will the third line be executed after the dir was deleted or while the directory is being deleted? Do I have to put the first command into a "Task" and wait until it is finished?

Comment: C# is synchronous by nature. Maybe you're a bit confused by al the new stuff about asynchrony in .NET. And also: I would imagine the reason for the downvotes being the fact that you formulated your question as a comment in the code example.

Comment: @bvgheluwe I really was a bit confused, I think it was because I had some stuff done in background workers recently and it was async and I had to create a Task for specific code and wait until it was finished. Sometimes I think too complicated, I guess.

Comment: @goodeinstein Don't you get me? o.O I HAD a problem :)

Comment: The question is fine, it just had an odd title and some bad formatting. Not sure why people would downvote instead of doing some simple edits or suggestions for improvement. Now that the edits are done and the question looks good it has -3 and an off-topic vote for no apparent reason.

Comment: @AndersForsgren I got some suggestion by some guy called schmaedeck. It's fine now, I guess :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is an older question but worth noting - `Directory.Delete` ultimately calls the `RemoveDirectory` Windows function, which *marks* the directory as to-be-deleted, but the filesystem won't *actually delete it* until all file handles are closed ([see docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365488(v=vs.85).aspx)). As a result it is perfectly possible to return from `Directory.Delete` and find the directory still exists.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your up-to-date answer :)

Comment: Appending: `while (Directory.Exists("someFolder")) Thread.Sleep(100);` after the `Delete` but before `Create` worked for me.

Comment: I was noticing issues with creating a folder sporadically failing the unit test due to the delay in the file system.  I add Refresh() to the DirectoryInfo object I was using and that fixed it.

Comment: > `while (Directory.Exists("someFolder")) Thread.Sleep(100);` and if something goes wrong, you loop forever... Please use a for loop with a fixed number of iterations instead and throw an exception if all the tries fail.

Comment: You might want to consider renaming the directory and then deleting it; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefile doesn't have the same caveat about being asynchronous, so maybe that it a reliable way to delete sort-of-synchronously.

Answer (score 4):

I also ran into this problem intermittently while running some integration tests that use the file system.

The "full" operation I wanted was to obtain an empty folder in which my process could perform its operations. The folder might already exist (with content) due to previous test runs, or it might not if either (a) the repo was freshly cloned or (b) I was adding new test cases.

Given [this illuminating answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43737996/402749), I realized [`Directory.Delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.delete?view=netframework-4.8) is a truly rotten plank on which to build this operation.

So I use this now:

```
public static DirectoryInfo EmptyDirectory(string directoryPath)
{
    var directory = Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);

    foreach (var file in directory.EnumerateFiles())
    {
        file.Delete();
    }

    foreach (var subdirectory in directory.EnumerateDirectories())
    {
        subdirectory.Delete(true);
    }

    return directory;
}
```

I also submitted a suggestion at the `Directory.Delete` doc page to add some kind of note about the underlying asynchronous nature of the method (at least on Windows, I guess). As far as leaky abstractions go, this is a pretty big leak.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to make recursive call to itself on each `subDirectory`?

Comment: @mxmissile For my purposes, no. I don't want to preserve the existing folder structure. But there's nothing wrong with that goal. Adjusting this logic to accomplish that should be pretty straightforward.