# Are either of os.rmdir or shutil.rmtree guaranteed or supposed to be synchronous on Windows?

Tags: python

It appears that shutil.rmtree is not synchronous on Windows, as I've had the second line in the following code raise an error that the directory already exists

```
shutil.rmtree(my_dir)
os.makedirs(my_dir) #intermittently raises Windows error 183 - already exists
```

We see a similar issue in .NET on windows - [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981143/is-directory-delete-create-synchronous) . Are there any good options to deal with this in python other than polling to see if the folder really is gone?

Comment: It is synchronous, but the directory simply was not deleted or recreated by another process.

Comment: On Windows, the **OS** can keep directories around if there are open files in those directories. Windows is lying to Python, there is little that can be done from Python code about this.

Comment: I realized I had ignore_errors as True passed into rmtree, so that may be part of the problem too. I'll see if I can repro without.

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with the folder still existing, and you're on Python 3, you can do [pass `exist_ok=True` to `os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs), and it will ignore the case where you try to make a directory that already exists:

```
shutil.rmtree(my_dir)
os.makedirs(my_dir, exist_ok=True)
```

Failing that, you're stuck polling. Run your code in a loop (ideally with a small sleep to avoid hammering the disk), and don't end the loop until the `makedirs` finishes without error:

```
import errno, os, shutil, time

while True:
    # Blow away directory
    shutil.rmtree(my_dir, ignore_errors=True)
    try:
        # Try to recreate
        os.makedirs(my_dir)
    except OSError as e:
        # If problem is that directory still exists, wait a bit and try again
        if e.winerror == 183:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            continue
        # Otherwise, unrecognized error, let it propagate
        raise
    else:
        # Successfully created empty dir, exit loop
        break
```

On Python 3.3+, you can probably change:

```
    except WindowsError as e:
        # If problem is that directory still exists, wait a bit and try again
        if e.errno == errno.EEXIST:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            continue
        # Otherwise, unrecognized error, let it propagate
        raise
```

to just:

```
    except FileExistsError:
        # If problem is that directory still exists, wait a bit and try again
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

as there is a specific exception type for "file exists" which you can catch directly (and let all other `OSError`/`WindowsError` exceptions propagate without interruption).

Comment: Even using `exist_ok=True` it still sometimes fails. While asynchronous `rmtree` deletion is going on, I don't see how creating with `exist_ok=True` could work.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution that worked for me:

```py
if os.path.isdir(destination):
    shutil.rmtree(destination)
while os.path.isdir(destination):
    pass
<other code>
```