# Is os.remove()+os.rmdir() better then shutil.rmtree()

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is safer and faster- to first delete entire dirs - with **os.remove(**) and then kill empty dir with **os.rmdir()**

-OR

just use **shutil.rmtree()** and kill all in one step  ?

(sorry, new to python)

Comment: There may be issues; check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662422/are-either-of-os-rmdir-or-shutil-rmtree-guaranteed-or-supposed-to-be-synchronous#47662642

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`os.remove()` throws an exception if the file doesn't exist, while `shutil.rmtree()` doesn't care if the directory is empty or not. Therefore, it is easier to use the latter in one step, rather than the former in addition to `os.rmdir()`(which would ideally require a `try-except` block or `os.path.isfile()` to ensure the file exists).

Comment: That's not the main issue though. `os.remove` will simply not work on a directory. `shutil.rmtree` is the right tool for the job, the first proposed approach of OP just won't work at all.

Comment: I believe the OP was planning to use `os.remove()` to delete files in a directory, and then use `os.rmdir()` to delete the empty directory, which works just fine.